# 1 ring traversal for Vertex Normal on an open model with boundary / Opengl, VC++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl

I am supposed to use one ring traversal to develop a mesh viewer for 3d objects whose input format is the  M-file format. I've done so far as to getting the face normals(of unit length) and it gives a correct flat shaded model. I'm now stuck with 1 ring traversal to obtain adjacent faces of a vertex when I encounter the boundary edge case whose twin edge is null. Thus my model is not correctly shaded for smooth shading. After a lot of research on this topic in many forums, though I did find a few good algorithms, I'm finding difficulty in practically implementing it. Below is the pseudo-code that I've used:

```
for each face
{
  compute and store face normals and face area(length/2)
}
for each vertex
{
  //compute adjacent faces using 1 ring traversal in clockwise and anticlockwise directions
  and store them in a vector for each vertex struct
  HE_edge* first_he = (*n)->edge;
  HE_edge* curr = first_he;
  while (curr->pair != NULL && curr->pair->prev != first_he)
  {
    compute sum of face areas for iterating vertex
    store curr->edge->face as adjacent face for vertex
    curr = curr->pair->next; //curr = curr->pair->previous in opposite CCW direction

    if (curr->pair == NULL)  break;
  }
}
for each vertex
{
  for each adjacent face
  {
    //compute vector normal as weighted avg of the areas of the faces
    vertex normal += (iterating adjacent face area/ sum of adjacent faces) * adjacent face normal;
  }
}`
```

So, I don't know what is wrong with the vertex normal part here that is giving me non-unit vectors as the vertex normals! I believe it is the 1-ring traversal that is causing the error and I have to use 1-ring traversal as per requirement!

For the area weights method as I've mentioned in my pseudo-code above, should I do the following?
    `face area = length of un-normalized face normal / 2
face sum = sum of all adjacent face areas
adjacent face's normal is the adjacent face's normal.x //similarly for y and z`
Am I messing up in any of the above three parts? Or even the 1 ring neighborhood traversal?!

Answer (score 0):

The weighted sum by face area percentage won't produce a unit vector unless all the faces are in the same direction.  Imagine once of the top corners of an open-box cube, two triangles point in the direction of one face (let's use the right, `x=1`), and one to the front (along `z=1`), but all three triangles have the same area (equally split sides of a cube into triangles). The final vector would be (1/3)(1,0,0) + (1/3)(1,0,0) + (1/3)(0,0,1) = (2/3,0,1/3) whose length is 0.745355.

[PBRT](http://www.pbrt.org) implements one-ring traversal for its subdivision surfaces and has full source code you can use a guide. It calculates the across tangent (S) and transverse tangent (T), performs a cross product and then normalizes to find the normals.

Comment: Thanks MtRoad, I get your point! But my project requires me to apply Weighted area vertex normal calculation as none of my objects have hard edges.

Comment: Now, I know this part theoretically as Nv = sum of (Si/S Nf) where Si is the face area of the i-th adjacent face and S is sum of face areas of all adjacent faces and Nf is the un-normalized face normal. My problem is I'm not correctly implementing it in my code! All my face normals are of unit length but my vertex normals are apparently not! So, either my error is in the 1 ring traversal(which is also the project requirement) OR my calculation of area weighted vertex normal! Have been trying hard and referring many articles, but unable to get to it!

Comment: I'd create a few cases by hand (I know it sucks, but it'll give you a metric) and try it out your algorithm by hand. Even with no hard edges, I think the math requires you to normalize. Is there a reason why you can't or shouldn't normalize it?  Since each adjacent face has a weighted contribution, normalizing still provides a correct, but scaled version of the contribution of each face's area weight and normal.